# Why won't the textField print date?

Tags: java, time

Why wont this  `tidField.setText(date);` work? Everything else works, the date is taken from `getDatum()` which is a diffrent class that works perfectly fine when called here `textArea.append(r.getLista());` but for `tidField.setText(date);` it wont change the field

```
 final JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
            comboBox.addItem("Företag");
            comboBox.addItem("Normal");
            comboBox.addItem("Student");
            comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    Kund kek = new Kund();
                    int kb = 0;
                    String date = kek.getDatum();
                    String SaldoString = "";
                    JComboBox<?> comboBox = (JComboBox<?>) event.getSource();
                    Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                     if(selected.toString().equals("Normal")) {
                            Register r = new Register();
                            Kund k = new Normal();
                            k.setBelopp(100);
                            k.setDatum(date);
                            r.regKund(k);
                            int tempbelopp = k.getBelopp();
                            String b = Integer.toString(tempbelopp);
                            tidField.setText(date);
                            beloppField.setText(b);
                            kb = kb + 100;
                            SaldoString = Integer.toString(kb);
                            saldoText.setText(SaldoString);
                            textArea.append(r.getLista()); 
                            }
                        else if(selected.toString().equals("Student")) {
                            Register r = new Register();
                            Kund k = new Normal();
                            k=new Student();
                            k.setBelopp(50);
                            k.setDatum(date);
                            beloppField.setText(date);
                            tidField.setText(date);
                            if( kb >=50)
                                r.regKund(k);
                                kb = kb - 50;

                                                    textArea.append("Det finns inga cash, student reggades ej!" + "\n");

                    }
                        else if(selected.toString().equals("Företag")) {
                            Register r = new Register();
                            Kund k = new Normal();
                            k.setBelopp(0);
                            k.setDatum("20:17");
                            k.setLopnummer(r.getLopnummer());
                            r.regKund(k);
                            // Den skriver ut samma skit ändra det
                            textArea.append(r.getLista());
                            textArea.append("Kassan har nu "+kb+" kr" + "\n");
                        }

                }
            });
            comboBox.setToolTipText("Välj vilken typ av Kund du är");
            comboBox.setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer("Välj..."));  
            //comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
            comboBox.setBounds(171, 46, 97, 22);        
            frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);


        }
        }
```

Comment: Can you print out the value of date after you have the line `String date = kek.getDatum();`?

Comment: Nope it wont print it out

Comment: Ok, this likely means there is an issue with that function and the thing that it is returning. Can you post the code for that function please?

Comment: Yea sure ill make a new post with the other classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue seems to be that in your constructor, you are setting `datum = ""`. After this, you never actualy use `setDatum()` so when you first call `getDatum()`, you are returning an empty String. If you change your constructor so that it uses a meaning default value, you should find that the first time it prints, it will add this value to the tidField.

Just to test this is the case, change your `datum = ""` to `datum = "hello"` so that you can see that you will actually be applying the text properly. The big thing is you will have to determine when you are going to call `setDatum()`.

After testing your code though, your textfield can be written to from code, but not edited by the user, so given the code your have provided, that seems to be the effect you were going for.

Comment: Thanks it worked now i did this  

 belopp= getBelopp();
 datum=setDatum(datum);
and changed public String setDatum(String d)  to a string
Thanks for help !

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty understanding what you have done as indicated by your comment, but if it is all working as expected, then that is the main thing!

Answer (score 0):

Code of the other classes

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Kund {

int belopp;
private String datum;

public Kund(){
    belopp=0;
    datum="";
}
// - Initiera attribut
public int getBelopp(){
    return belopp;

}
// - Returnera belopp
public void setBelopp(int b){
    belopp=b;
}
// - Sätta belopp
public String getDatum() {
    return datum;
}
// - Returnera datum
public void setDatum(String d) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    d = format.format(date);
    datum=d;
}
// - Sätta datum
public int nyBalans(int n) {
    return (n+this.getBelopp());
}
// - Returnera tidigare balans + aktuellt belopp
// - Överlagras i Student
public void setLopnummer(int x) {

}
// - Överlagras i Foretag

}



public class Frame extends Register {
private int TempInt;
    JFrame frame;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Frame window = new Frame();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Programmet sparas och kommer nu stängas av");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Frame() {

        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 424);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);




        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);        
        textArea.setBounds(0, 105, 440, 243);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);


        // Använd k.setBelopp beroende på vilken man väljer


        String s = "";
        int il = beraknaSaldo();
        s = Integer.toString(il);
        final JTextPane saldoText = new JTextPane();
        saldoText.setText(s);
        saldoText.setEditable(false);
        saldoText.setBounds(208, 354, 42, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(saldoText);

        final TextField beloppField = new TextField();
        beloppField.setEditable(false);
        beloppField.setBounds(120, 10, 102, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(beloppField);


        final TextField tidField = new TextField();
        tidField.setEditable(false);
        tidField.setBounds(255, 10, 102, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tidField);

        Label saldoLabel = new Label("Saldo:");
        saldoLabel.setBounds(162, 354, 40, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(saldoLabel);

        Label beloppLabel = new Label("Belopp:");
        beloppLabel.setBounds(72, 10, 50, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(beloppLabel);

        Label tidLabel = new Label("Tid:");
        tidLabel.setBounds(228, 10, 22, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tidLabel);

        Label besökartypLabel = new Label("Bes\u00F6kartyp");
        besökartypLabel.setBounds(0, 77, 62, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(besökartypLabel);

        Label beloppLabel_1 = new Label("Belopp");
        beloppLabel_1.setBounds(122, 77, 62, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(beloppLabel_1);

        Label tidLabel_1 = new Label("Tid");
        tidLabel_1.setBounds(246, 77, 22, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tidLabel_1);

        Label lopnrLabel = new Label("L\u00F6pnummer");
        lopnrLabel.setBounds(345, 77, 79, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lopnrLabel);

        final JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.addItem("Företag");
        comboBox.addItem("Normal");
        comboBox.addItem("Student");
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                Kund kek = new Kund();
                int kb = 0;
                String date = kek.getDatum();
                String SaldoString = "";
                JComboBox<?> comboBox = (JComboBox<?>) event.getSource();
                Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                 if(selected.toString().equals("Normal")) {
                     textArea.append(date);
                        /*Register r = new Register();
                        Kund k = new Normal();
                        k.setBelopp(100);
                        k.setDatum(date);
                        r.regKund(k);
                        int tempbelopp = k.getBelopp();
                        String b = Integer.toString(tempbelopp);
                        tidField.setText(date);
                        beloppField.setText(b);
                        kb = kb + 100;
                        SaldoString = Integer.toString(kb);
                        saldoText.setText(SaldoString);
                        textArea.append(r.getLista()); */
                        }
                    else if(selected.toString().equals("Student")) {
                        Register r = new Register();
                        Kund k = new Normal();
                        k=new Student();
                        k.setBelopp(50);
                        k.setDatum(date);
                        beloppField.setText(date);
                        tidField.setText(date);
                        if( kb >=50)
                            r.regKund(k);
                            kb = kb - 50;

                                                textArea.append("Det finns inga cash, student reggades ej!" + "\n");

                }
                    else if(selected.toString().equals("Företag")) {
                        Register r = new Register();
                        Kund k = new Normal();
                        k.setBelopp(0);
                        k.setDatum("20:17");
                        k.setLopnummer(r.getLopnummer());
                        r.regKund(k);
                        // Den skriver ut samma skit ändra det
                        textArea.append(r.getLista());
                        textArea.append("Kassan har nu "+kb+" kr" + "\n");
                    }

            }
        });
        comboBox.setToolTipText("Välj vilken typ av Kund du är");
        comboBox.setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer("Välj..."));  
        //comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        comboBox.setBounds(171, 46, 97, 22);        
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);


    }
    }


class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {
    private String title;

    public MyComboBoxRenderer(String newTitle) {
        title = newTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (index == -1 && value == null) setText(title );
        else setText(value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should actually add this code as an edit to your question, just to make sure that others are clear this is not an answer. I have copied this code so that I am able to check while/if you place it in your question.